# How to debug Android code for an unexpected value?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and doing some basic activities on Android Studio. I have the following code which will redirect from LoginActivity to Navigation activity after successful login.

**LoginActivity.java code:**

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;


/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "test@gmail.com:hello"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    private boolean loginPassed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if(!cancel) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                focusView = mPasswordView;
                cancel = true;
            } else if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
                focusView = mPasswordView;
                cancel = true;
            }
        }



        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);

            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);

            if(loginPassed) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Test");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
            loginPassed = success;
            if (success) {
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter valid Email and Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setMargin(100,50);
                toast.show();
                /*mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();*/
                mEmailView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

***loginPassed*** variable is set to true if the credentials are correct else it will be false.

If I remove ***if*** condition in the above program if will redirect to NavigationActivity properly but with ***if*** condition in place, it will simple close the application.

Not sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Please write a title that describes your problem.

Comment: Well, maybe `loginPassed` isn't set to any value afterall and the app crashes due to a `NullPointerException`. There's no way to tell from the code snippet, but you should be able to debug your application to follow what happens to `loginPassed`.

Comment: Show us the code that declares / initializes and sets `loginPassed`.  The obvious explanation is that it is `false`.

Comment: I have used instance variable loginPassed and setting value in the code after validation

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a global variable  *loginPassed*

```
Boolean loginPassed;
```

Then you have to execute the AsyncTask for check the user credentials like this -

```
new UserLoginTask().execute();
```

Now in AsyncTask we will check the user's credentials and make operations accordingly

```
class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
   String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

   protected void onPreExecute (){
      super.onPreExecute();
      Log.d(TAG + " PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
    }

   protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG + " DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");

    if(validate(email, password))
        loginPassed = true;
    else
        loginPassed = false;

    return "";
   }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
    super.onProgressUpdate(a);
    Log.d(TAG + " onProgressUpdate", "You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.d(TAG + " onPostExecute", "" + result);

    if(loginPassed){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Jefry");
        startActivity(intent);

     }else{
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at my code and tell me what;s wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `loginPassed` var, but never place values in it. 
When you create a `boolean` var the default value is `false`, them the runtime never enter in this `if(loginPassed)`